# How to prepopulate React Google Places Autocomplete input field from url and allow user to clear or type in new locations

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am using the google places autocomplete npm package in a form like this:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
 apiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY} 
 debounce={200}
 selectProps={{
 value: location, //received from setLocation state
 defaultValue: location, //received from setLocation state
 defaultInputValue: location, //received from setLocation state
 onChange: (param,e)=>{
   param?.label !== undefined ? getCoordinates(param.label) : clearValue()
   param?.value.place_id ? setPlaceId(param.value.place_id) : null
   },
 isClearable: true,
 placeholder: 'Search locations',
 styles: { 
  singleValue: (base, state) => 
   ({ ...base, color: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? "#DCDCDC" : base.color }) },
 menuPlacement: 'auto',
 instanceId: 'places_autocomplete',
 }}
 autocompletionRequest={{
 componentRestrictions: {
 country: ['gh'],
 }
 }}

 inputClassName="google-places-autocomplete-input"
 />
```

When user submits the form, I do a route.push({}) which includes the location, lat, lng and placeId as query params in the url like this: `http://localhost:3000/listings?location=Tesano&lat=5.605703399999999&lng=-0.2353967&placeId=ChIJa4GWSXaZ3w8REb4FSUWihoQ&search=1`

Now if the user should refresh the page, the url stays the same which is the correct behaviour but the search input field value is lost. I tried usign useEffect to pre-populate the search field but its not working. When I use the `value, defaultValue or defaultInputValue` of the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` component, I am either unable to type in and select new locations or when I select a new location, it disappaers. What is the right way to go about this. Thanks in advance